# Changing the written data in a Writer monad

Tags: haskell, monads

Given a `Writer` monad action, I want to modify it by mapping a function over the written data inside the monad action.

Something like:

```
retell :: (w -> w') -> Writer w a -> Writer w' a
```

Does such a function already exists in the libraries? If not, how can one be defined?

Comment: Can you do this by chaining the `pass` method in the MonadWriter class? If not I'd make my own subclass of Writer - `Rewriter` that provides a `retell` operation.

Comment: @stephentetley - correcting myself, as you want to type change the `w` of the Writer monad you can't do this with `pass`. I would go with a `Rewriter` subclass that extends `Writer` with `retell`.

Answer (score 11):

```
retell f = Writer . second f $ runWriter
```

There is also a `mapWriter` function provided by the libraries. So you could do this:

```
retell = mapWriter . second
```

The `second` function is in `Control.Arrow`, but you can define a less general version of it yourself like this:

```
second f (a, b) = (a, f b)
```